# exception of nullpinter when using getText() method:

Tags: java, swing, exception, nullpointerexception

i built a code in Frame class and call another class frame named search which contains bottun.
and i try to add this button action :

```
           s=new Search();
           s.button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {

            String a =s.text_1.getText();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame() ,a);...
```

I try to run this but it says

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException..
```

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Hi DANA. Welcome to StackOverflow. I hope you find as much use out of it as I have. Just as an FYI, please take a look through this page on refactoring your questions to get the best answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
I hope it's useful.

Comment: Based on the code snippet, I'd "guess" that `text_1` is `null`

Comment: so why when i try to get from textBox it works? and how can i fix this?

Comment: In the future, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: My best "guess" would that you are shadowing your variables, creating a instance field called `text_1` is never assigned a value and a local one, which is the one you use to create the UI